# Does there exist similar thing as #'asdf:system-relative-pathname in CL?

Tags: haskell

In Common Lisp, we can use

```
(namestring (asdf:system-relative-pathname 'money "money.dat"))
```

to get the absolute path of `money.dat`. It is VERY convenient as this data file is position independent.

Suppose there is a `Money.hs` module which manipulates a data file `money.dat` in the same directory `DIR-1`. Because it is using relative path, i have to `cd DIR-1` to make `money.dat` visible to this module.  Now if I `ghc-pkg register` this module, can I make `money.dat` visible to `Money.hs` no matter where the current directory is ?

Comment: See: [Accessing data files from package code](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#accessing-data-files-from-package-code), [Adding data files using Cabal](http://neilmitchell.blogspot.no/2008/02/adding-data-files-using-cabal.html).

Comment: it is the haskell way. thanks !

Comment: @hammar: you should post your response as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As per hammar's comment, we can set up a `data-dir` in our `.cabal` file which contains data files that get deployed when a package is `cabal install`'d. Then, using the [instructions in the Cabal manual](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#accessing-data-files-from-package-code) we can programmatically access those files from our installed libraries.